# How to make `arc land` check local and phabricator review are in sync?

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

Consider the following workflow:

1. make some changes
2. `git add . && git commit -am 'update 1'`
3. `arc diff`, now local and phabricator code review are in sync
4. make some further changes and `git commit -a --amend --no-edit`
5. `arc land` and the local amended (unreviewed) changes are happily accepted by Arcanist and gets merged to master.

Apparently, if I don't do `--amend` in step 4 and create another commit, `arc land` would fail complaining a mismatch. But I would like to configure Arcanist so that with `--amend` `arc land` can fail as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `arc` command I am using is monkey patched by my employer and there is a bug in the patch.